# failed to convert my ggplot to interactive plot using ggplotly function

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm making a stacked barplot. The width of the bar is set according to variable `w`.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(x = c("a","b","c"),
                w = c(1.2, 1.3, 4),
                y = c(9, 10, 6) )

dat = df %>% mutate(pos = 0.5 * (cumsum(w) + cumsum(c(0, w[-length(w)]))))

g= dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = pos,  y = y, fill = x)) + 
  geom_bar(aes( width = w), stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = df$x, breaks =  dat$pos)

ggplotly(g)
```

The ggplot is fine. But when I tried to convert it to interactive using `ggplotly`, I got error message as below:

```
Error in nchar(axisObj$ticktext) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector
```

Does anyone know why this failed? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is your x-axis scaling.

This should work:

```r
library(plotly)
  library(tidyverse)

  df = data.frame(x = c("a","b","c"),
                  w = c(1.2, 1.3, 4),
                  y = c(9, 10, 6) )

  dat = df %>% mutate(pos = 0.5 * (cumsum(w) + cumsum(c(0, w[-length(w)]))))

  g= dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = pos,  y = y, fill = x)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(width = w), stat = "identity") + 
    scale_x_continuous(labels = levels(df$x), breaks =  dat$pos)

  ggplotly(g)
```

`ggplot` seems to keep your x-axis labels as factor-levels which `ggplotly` doesn't understand.
So you just need to convert them to `character`.